# Concatenate / merge mp3 files in date range

Tags: batch-file, merge, vbscript, concatenation

I use the code below to concatenate/merge mp3 files.

All my directories are in `yyyymmdd` format.

The first `copy /b` line, `%result%\%result%\mp3\*.mp3`, is the same `20210123\20210123`

`set day=0` is `20210123` *(today)*, if I change to
`-1`, it is `20210122` *(yesterday)*, `-35`, `20201219`, `1`, `20210124` *(tomorrow)* etc.

This is working, and concats mp3 my files very well, but how can I change it to working in a date range?

example:

`day=0` ->  `day=-35`, i.e. `20210123`-`20201219`

I think I need to do some loop, but I don't know how.

Plus question, `copy /b`, all the time overwrites output mp3 file when I run my .bat, is it possible to "auto" skip if it already exists?

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
set day=0
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "result=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%"
copy /b %result%\%result%\mp3\*.mp3 %result%\"podcastsí-%result%-all.mp3"
copy /b %result%\mp3\*.mp3 %result%\"podcastsí-%result%-all.mp3"
pause
```

Comment: copy /b need sometimes 20-30 or more files in directori and without /b just copy the first one

Comment: Apologies, I had not engaged my brain when posting that, now deleted comment. You do appear to be copying multiple files into one, so yes, you will need the `/B` option. All you need to do, is check if the file exists first, like this: `If Exist "%result%\"podcastsí-%result%-all.mp3" (Copy /B …)`. You can find out more about the `If` command, by typing `if /?`, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key, in a Command Prompt window. As for your main question, you appear to be expecting new code to be added, as opposed to assistance fixing something. That is off topic here, we don't provide code to request.

Comment: thank you thats helpful too! sry, next time i'm not use both in one post! and also thanks to edited my post to english! :)

Comment: Of course, once you've read the information you should quickly see the deliberate error in what I posted above too. Although I'd have been less inclined to be deliberately vague, had I noticed somebody had already provided you with an answer, to your off topic code request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```batch-file
@echo OFF

set day=0
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "dayend=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"

set day=-35
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "daystart=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"


:: My system sets daystart and dayend to yyyymmdd format. Yours may need to be re-calculated.
:: Following if exist looks for directory named "%%y\%%y\mp3" and skips if missing

:: Caution : I have modified your name to "podcasts" below to suit my system

FOR /L %%y IN (%daystart%,1,%dayend%) DO IF EXIST %%y\%%y\mp3\. (
 IF NOT EXIST %%y\"podcasts-%%y-all.mp3" copy /b %%y\%%y\mp3\*.mp3 %%y\"podcasts-%%y-all.mp3" >nul
 IF NOT EXIST %%y\"podcasts-%%y-all.mp3" COPY /b %%y\mp3\*.mp3 %%y\"podcasts-%%y-all.mp3" >nul
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I'm not really sure about the two *copy* commands-per-directory executed and would suggest that the `copy` be changed to `echo copy` to show the proposed operation for verification.

Comment: this is awesome :) 
i duplicate your FOR /L and mod a little and now working both
%%y\mp3\*.mp3 ; %%y\%%y\mp3\*.mp3 
and also can't overwrite my files cool :)    thank you!